# Integrate: $\int \frac {e^{6x}}{\sqrt {1-e^{3x}}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate: $\int \dfrac {e^{6x}}{\sqrt {1-e^{3x}}} dx$

My Attempt:
$$=\int \dfrac {e^{6x}}{\sqrt {1-e^{3x}}} dx$$
Let $e^x = t$
$$dt=e^x.dx$$
Now,
$$=\int \dfrac {t^5}{\sqrt {1-t^3}} dt$$

Comment: If $t=e^x$, how is $e^{6x}=t^5$?

Comment: @YashJain $e^{6x} = t^5 \, dt$.

Comment: @YashJain, $e^{6x}=e^{5x}.e^x$ so..

Comment: This website may help in the future https://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: Never mind. I understand.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: A far better substitution might by

$$t = 1 - e^{3x}$$

which entirely deals with the radical. This is motivated by the fact that the constant is immaterial after differentiating.

Answer (score 1):

let $u = e^{3x}$.

Your integral becomes

$$ \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u}} du = $$  Now letting $u = v +1$

Your integral becomes 
$$ \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{v}{\sqrt{v}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{v}} du $$

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun using differentials directly:

$\int \frac{e^{6x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{3x}}}dx=\int \frac{e^{3x}e^{3x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{3x}}}dx =\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1-e^{3x}-1}{\sqrt{1-e^{3x}}}d(1-e^{3x})=$ $\frac{1}{3}\int\sqrt{1-e^{3x}}d(1-e^{3x})-\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{3x}}}d(1-e^{3x})=\frac{2}{9}(1-e^{3x})\sqrt{1-e^{3x}}-\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{1-e^{3x}}= -\frac{2}{9}\sqrt{1-e^{3x}}(2+e^{3x})$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $$I=\int \dfrac {e^{6x}}{\sqrt {1-e^{3x}}}\,dx$$ To get rid of the radical, let 
$$\sqrt {1-e^{3x}}=t^2 \implies x=\frac{1}{3} \log \left(1-t^4\right)\implies dx=-\frac{4 t^3}{3 \left(1-t^4\right)}\,dt$$ making
$$I=\frac{4}{3} \int t \left(t^4-1\right)\,dt$$